# How does recursion work for active patterns in F#?

Tags: parsing, f#, metaprogramming

I have the following function for parsing an integer:

```
let rec digits = function
    | head::tail when System.Char.IsDigit(head) ->
        let result = digits tail
        (head::(fst result), snd result)
    | rest -> ([], rest)
```

If I change this function to be an active recognizer, it no longer compiles.

```
let rec (|Digits|) = function
    | head::tail when System.Char.IsDigit(head) ->
        let result = Digits tail
        (head::(fst result), snd result)
        //          ^^^^^^       ^^^^^^ see error*
    | rest -> ([], rest)
```

> *error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type char list * 'a but here has type
>   char list

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
let rec (|Digits|) = function
    | head::(Digits (a, b)) when System.Char.IsDigit(head) -> (head::a, b)
    | rest -> ([], rest)
```

NOTE: 
if you want to use active pattern as a function you still can do it:

```
let rec (|Digits|) = function
    | head::tail when System.Char.IsDigit(head) ->
        let a, b = (|Digits|) tail
        (head::a, b)
    | rest -> ([], rest)
```

Comment: Ahh, I see. I was just looking at [this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Active_Patterns#Parameterizing_Active_Patterns). This makes sense, given that the return type is also part of the rule (if my terminology isn't wrong). Thanks very much!